# Find all entities that are missing a particular attribute

Tags: datomic

In my schema I have the attribute `:base/type` that is supposed to exist for every entity created. To check that this is indeed true, I'm trying to find entities where it is missing:

```
[:find [?entities ...]
 :in $ :where
 [(missing? $ ?entities :base/type)]]
```

Unfortunately this gives me back:

```
Execution error (Exceptions$IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo) at datomic.error/arg (error.clj:57).
:db.error/insufficient-binding [?entities] not bound in expression clause: [(missing? $ ?entities :base/type)]
```

How should this query be constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your query is too general. You need at least one positive clause in where statement if you use query API. You can access raw index to get the result, though. If you have enough RAM, you can:

```
(def snapshot (d/db connection)) ; your db snapshot
(def all-datoms (d/datoms snapshot :eavt))
(def base-type-id (:db/id (d/entity snapshot :base/type))  
(def entities (group-by #(.e %) all-datoms))
(def entities-without-base-type (map 
                                  (comp #(into {} %) (partial d/entity snapshot) first) 
                                  (filter (fn [[k l]] 
                                          (empty? (filter #(= base-type-id (.a %)) 
                                        l))) 
                                   entities)))
(def only-relevant-entities (filter #(not (or (:db/ident %) (:db/txInstant %))) entities-without-base-type))

only-relevant-entities
```

The last filter is to get rid of attribute definitions and transactions (they are stored as datoms in the db as well!).

If you have too many entities you can chunk datoms using the async atoms API.

Comment: Your answer is for on-prem only and whilst educational isn't as practical as just adding in a positive clause that is definitely in an entity. That's the solution I used - the downside being that (to technically answer the question, as you have done) you'll have to find the set of such attributes that cover all entities created by the Datomic developer.

Comment: Exactly. The answer I have provided resides in the first two sentences. The rest is a curious side note if the answer is not practical enough. I found raw index access necessary at times as the query API does not provide certain functionalities I sometimes need. I did not need to load the whole db into ram as yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `::singer/songs` as an example attribute, this is how to do the query:

```
[:find [?entities ...]
 :in $ :where
 [?entities ::singer/songs ?s]
 [(missing? $ ?entities :base/type)]]
```

Unfortunately (in my answer) many such queries would be required until the whole database has been covered. So another query with `::song/composers`, etc...